# Failed to decrypt web.config file - Encryption using 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvide'

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, connection-string, sitefinity

I want to encrypt `connection string` in `my web.config` file. I followed [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/795135/Encrypt-ConnectionString-in-Web-Config) and got encrypted connection string. I followed follwing steps

1. Run command prompt as admin
2. Reached `aspnet_regiis`
3. Emcryted using command `ASPNET_REGIIS -pef "connectionStrings" "D:\ProjPath"`

It got encrypted but when I run my app, I am getting this error

```
Failed to decrypt using provider 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider: The RSA key container could not be opened.
```

on line `<EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"`

I am getting this error on **local machine** means there is no chance of machine key problem and when I decrypt it using `ASPNET_REGIIS -pdf "connectionStrings" "D:\ProjPath"` then I am getting proper connectionstring.

**Also** is there any way to encrypt connection string in `DataConfig.Config` file in `Sitefinity`

Answer (score 0):

try in this way

1. Go on the IIS and chose the site where the problem is
2. Home -->Authentication double click
3. Disable ASP.NET impersonation

this should solve your problem

you can disable it in web config under system.web

```
<identity impersonate="false"/>
```

**update**

I think that could be a problem with the exportation of the keys

try with this commands ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

```
aspnet_regiis -pc "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" -exp
aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "ASPNET"
aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "NETWORK SERVICE"
aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
```

Comment: I am running this on local machine, is there involvement of IIS here?

Comment: First command executed successfully but second one throwing error on console `The trust relationship between this workstation and primary domain failed <Exception from HRESULT:0x800706FD>`

Comment: ASPNET, NETWORK SERVICE, NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE should be valid users name (or group), replace them (one command is sufficient) with the name of the user that is logged to the machine and let me know

Comment: I replace "ASPNET" with "SGTECH\devuser16" that's user and it executed. All the commands are looking same now after replacing "NETWORK SERVICE" and "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" am I doing it right?

Comment: yes, let me know if it solve your problem, for any help I'm here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67844/discussion-between-imad-and-faby).

Comment: Check which is the user that execute iis during debug and put it as parameter instead of your windows user

Comment: Seems like my project do not run on IIS but on inbuilt web server that is “ASP.NET Development Server”.

Comment: Put the user that execute that process as  second parameter in regiis -pa